# How to update all volume values at 09:31m for each stock in DolphinDB?

Tags: dolphindb

I’m using DolphinDB for historical data processing.
Can I update the field “volume” at 09:31m for each market stock with the summed values at 09:31m and 09:30m?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following the code:

```
t = table(`A`A`A`A`B`B`B`B as symbol, 09:28m 09:29m 09:30m 09:31m 09:28m 09:29m 09:30m 09:31m as minute, 10 20 30 40 20 15 25 10 as volume)
update t  set volume = volume+move_volume from (select *,move(volume,1) from t context by symbol) where minute = 09:31m
```